# Return an entire object where filter and includes matches

Tags: javascript

I currently have several objects like so:

```
// not correct syntax just showing what members is
       const members = "-Lz8YxIL-XJotORQ3Bk1": Object {
            "address": "14539 Fasdfadsfrd Ave",
            "bDay": "10/01/2004",
            "city": "Norwalk",
            "email": "wasdfsadfga2@yahoo.com",
            "first": "Frank",
        }, ...
```

I also have an object with a few UIDs like so:

```
const attendanceGroup.members =  {
  "-MxQvetKWRGNVO6EWIko": "-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn",
  "-MxSvxI-D53qlXtp1nzT": "-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn",
}
```

I would like to get the object returned of each object where the uid matches.
I'm doing it like so:

```
  const groupMembers = Object.keys(members).filter(item => {
    return Object.values(attendanceGroup.members).includes(item);
  });
```

But this only returns the keys of the matching uid.  I would like the whole object.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: then don't filter `Object.keys(members)` ... filter `members` instead - by the way, your `const members` is not valid javascript at all - please rectify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.entries` will give you the key, value pairs:

```js
const attendanceGroupMembers = new Set(Object.values(attendanceGroup.members));
const groupMembers = Object.entries(members)
  .filter(([key]) => attendanceGroupMembers.has(key))
  .map(([_, members]) => members);
```